# Concurent Threading in Rust: What does "join on handle" perform?

Tags: multithreading, rust, concurrency, mutex

In the following code from [Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.4.0/book/dining-philosophers.html) it talks about concurrent threading in Rust.

```
    use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
    use std::thread;
    
    fn main() {
        let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
        let mut handles = vec![];
    
        for _ in 0..10 {
            let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
            let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
                let mut num = counter.lock().unwrap();
    
                *num += 1;
            });
            handles.push(handle);
        }
    
        for handle in handles {
            handle.join().unwrap();
        }
    
        println!("Result: {}", *counter.lock().unwrap());
    }
```

I still couldn't grasp the idea of the for loop for the handles

i.e

```
for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
```

The documentation says *"we call join on each handle to make sure all the threads finish. "*
For an experiment I commented out the handle for loop and I got an out put of 8 instead of 10. When I changed the loop to 1000, I got 999 when the handle loop is commented. What is happening here ? How does 8 & 999 become the output ?

**EDIT:** I found [this documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.4.0/book/dining-philosophers.html) to touch on handle and general concept of threading.

```
  [1]: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html
```

Comment: The notion of joining threads isn't something Rust-specific. To join a thread means to wait for a thread to finish.

Comment: There is no point guessing why you get 8 or 999. Execution order of threads is OS business and unspecified, that's why you wait for them with `join()`.

Comment: Nitpick: it is better to use atomics than `Mutex` for primitives.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I agree. I was just experimenting with Arc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I still couldn't grasp the idea of the for loop for the handles

What is there to grasp? `JoinHandle::join` blocks until the corresponding thread is done executing (so the function has reached its end), that's most of what there is to it (usefully it also yields whatever the thread's function has returned).

> When I changed the loop to 1000, I got 999 when the handle loop is commented. What is happening here ? How does 8 & 999 become the output ?

When you don't `join` on the threads, you have a race between the threads and the main thread (the `main` function). The value you get is however many threads have executed the increment in the time it took to

1. create all the threads
2. add each threads to the vector
3. get a lock on the counter

This will change depending on system load and OS scheduling details, though most of the delay of the main thread will be... spawning more threads (compared to spawning a thread, acquiring a lock and incrementing a number is cheap) which is why most of the threads are done by the time you print the results. If you increase per-thread work, or change the way the threads are spawned, you will see different races.

Comment: The reason we get 8 & 999 is probably coming from the main thread's println() being executed before all threads finished updating the counter ?

Comment: I'd say there's no "probably" about it. If all the threads had finished updating the counter, you'd get 10 and 1000.

Answer (score 1):

What [join()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join) does is simply wait for the thread to finish. It asks the OS to block the main thread (the one calling `join()`) until the joined thread is done, and collect its status.

Before calling `join()`, you only know that you have handed the thread to the OS. You don't know later in the code if it has already been started, is running, has finished, was killed by the OS, or has panic()'ed, etc.

The only thing you know about your shared `counter` before calling `join()` is that you can read it in a consistent state (thanks to the mutex). That is, without risking a race-condition between the main thread and another thread that may be in the middle of incrementing it.